# How to run multiples services in parallel in a single Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Let's say I have 3 services, `service1`, `service2` and `service3`. To save money and keep the deployment simple I plan to run them in a single Docker container, instead of one for each. How can I define my `ENTRYPOINT` ?

If I run them in the background:

```
ENTRYPOINT service1 & service2 & service3 &
```

the command will exit, and so will my Container do.

If I run them sequentially:

```
ENTRYPOINT service1 && service2 && service3

or

ENTRYPOINT service1; service2; service3
```

`service1` it will block, and `service2` will start only after `service1` will stop running.

I even tried with `GNU parallel`:

```
ENTRYPOINT (service1; service2; service3) | parallel
```

But same behavior, `service2` starts only after `service1` is stopped

So how can I have the 3 services running concurrently as one service, so my Container will only exit when all services are stopped ?

Comment: So `wait` for the services. But it's way better to use `supervisord` or another tool that.. supervisors your serivces.

Comment: I don't get the point, each service is supposed to be running forever, what should I wait for exactly ?

Comment: You should run this in three separate containers.  There are prebuilt tools like Docker Compose that support this, and it will be simpler and more maintainable than trying to make "the single main container process" run multiple things.  The overall disk/memory/CPU utilization should be very similar.

Comment: I know Docker Compose, I was exactly trying to avoid using it. It is easier to maintain for sure, but buying a Container isn't that easy. I just want to know if my scenario is possible

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ ?

Comment: Does a script work with `service1&; service2&; service3&; wait` and `ENTRYPOINT script`?

Comment: @Walter, just what I needed, the wait command fix everything. I also found more options at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ thanks @ hmm. So my scenario is not that wrong.

Comment: @WalterA it works without the semicolons: `service1& service2& service3& wait`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(first proposed as a comment)
Start the services in the background and keep the docker container alive:

service1& service2& service3& wait